# Use progress/activity indicator waiting for await to finish

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an async function. I'm using it correctly. Here's what it looks like:

```
Future<void> getData() async
{
// get data from DB
}
```

It works. I call it from the

```
void initState  ()
{
    super.initState();

    getData();
}
```

I would like to make sure that there is a progress indicator running until the function has completed whatever it was doing.

Can someone help me with that? I have no idea where to begin.

Parts of this function get completed at whatever time/speed it takes it each command to finish, but I need to wait for the entire getData() function to finish completely before my app starts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Have a stateful widget before Home Screen**
2. **pushReplace Screen after fetch database completed**

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: LoadingScreen(),
      routes: {
        '/homePage': (context){
          return HomePage();
        },
      },
    );
  }
}


class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  Future<void> getData() async {
    // get data from DB
  }

  void navigationPage() async {
    await getData();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homePage');

  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigationPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While ejabu's solution works, it is far from perfect and calling asynchronous functions without await, especially in `initState` is a *big* nono.

Just like everything in Flutter, if you have a problem, there's a widget for that.
The ideal widget for rendering a page after a Future completed is `FutureBuilder` ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)).
`FutureBuilder` is a *dead* useful widget. You can use it for any widget that has to have a Future complete before it is built.

For example, if an app requires the user to sign in to Google, initialize a few APIs, **then** show the homepage, then you can use a `FutureBuilder` to show a progress indicator when the Future is running, an error page when an error occurs, or the homepage if all goes well and the Future completes without errors.

Here's a quick example from the build method of a widget:

```java
Widget build() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: futureFunction(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // Future done with no errors
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          !snapshot.hasError) {
        return HomePage();
      }

      // Future with some errors
      else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("The error ${snapshot.error} occured");

      // Future not done yet
      else {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 10),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Can I quickly rant about how terrible the editor in Stack Overflow is. It caused me to accidently post my answer before I was done :(